# htaccess rewrite dynamic mp3 to dynamic php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Using htaccess, is it possible to rewrite something like:

```
http://www.example.com/music.mp3?file= filname
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/mp3.php?file= filname
```

so when an user goes to ( music.mp3?file= filname ) he will be rewrite to ( music.php?mp3file= filname ) ....

Comment: in short yes its possible :)

Comment: you could even do 'http:// www.example.com/filename.mp3' to 'http:// www.example.com/mp3.php?file= filename'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this example send request from `music.mp3?any-query` or `music.mp3` to a `music.php?any-query`

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^music.mp3(.*)$ music.php$1 [r=301,L]
```

this example send request from `file-name.mp3` to a `music.php?file=file-name`

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*).mp3$ music.php?file=$1 [r=301,L]
```

Comment: Chec it out now. You must save the `.htaccess` file in the root of the server. e.g. `http://example.com/.htaccess`