# How to rewrite mp3 filename using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, pcre

I'm tried to protect my mp3 using mod_rewrite in my htaccess file.

I read this threads:

[how to write a .htaccess redirect like stackoverflow does for its questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583106/how-to-write-a-htaccess-redirect-like-stackoverflow-does-for-its-questions?rq=1)

[htaccess rewrite dynamic mp3 to dynamic php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074440/htaccess-rewrite-dynamic-mp3-to-dynamic-php)

[How to hide filename from url by using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722088/how-to-hide-filename-from-url-by-using-htaccess)

this website:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

and this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPlZekNEU60

I was able to rewrite filename to filename.pdf with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.pdf -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.pdf [NC,L]
```

Now, to protect my mp3 I want to rewrite my url

filename.mp3/?uuid=something to https://cdn.com/123456/t/filename.mp3

I tried this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.mp3 -f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{30})$ https://cdn.com/123456/t/$1.mp3 [NC,L]
```

but it doesn't work

I tried this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w*.mp3)+)$ https://cdn.com/123456/t/$1 [NC,L]
```

but it puts the website down :(

Any tip?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this weekend I'll try your solution and I'll keep you updated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your last `RewriteRule` has a closing parenthesis too much at the end and will repeat matching mp3 1 or more times.

If you remove that parenthesis leaving `^(\w*.mp3)+` it will still repeat one or more times a grouping structure that will match this pattern `\w*.mp3`. That will match 0+ times a word character followed by any character due to the dot and `mp3`.

That could for example match `zmp3`. If you want to match a literal dot you have to escape it.

I think that you meant:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+\.mp3/)$ https://cdn.com/123456/t/$1 [NC,L]
```

You  might check if the querystring consist of a single key/value pair:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uuid=\w+$ [NC]
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work 
`RewriteRule ^(\w*.mp3)+)$ https://cdn.com/123456/t/$1 [NC,L]`
When I click the link of the mp3, it's not rewrote :(

Comment: @PonzioPilato What you tried is slightly different from `RewriteRule ^(\w+\.mp3/)$ https://cdn.com/123456/t/$1 [NC,L]` Did you try that?